# Saving levelplot() to file in R's lattice package

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

I noticed something really weird happening in my script:

```
pdf("name.pdf")
levelplot(my_data)
dev.off()
```

does not work for `lattice`'s levelplot if I want to save the plot to a file. I read the `lattice` package manual and the levelplot help function but couldn't find anything about this particular problem.

Comment: What do you mean my "does not work"? The pdf file is blank? Can you provide more information about your data? It's working fine for me here.

Comment: Yes. it creates an empty pdf file. Thanks to Gavin Simpson's answer I know now, that I have to use `print()`. However, this only works in an interactive session for me now, and I would like to know how to do it from a R script.

Comment: Then there is something else wrong as this *does* work in non-interactive sessions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By "script" I am presuming that you are not running this interactively? Anyway, simply calling a grid-based graphics function (such as those in the **lattice** or **ggplot2** packages) does **not** do any plotting - it just creates the an R object that describes the plot. You need to `print` this object to get R to draw the plot.

In interactive use, the object gets auto-printed, but not in a script (and not in a loop for example).

Try:

```
pdf("name.pdf")
print(levelplot(my_data))
dev.off()
```

If that doesn't work you'll need to explain more as I can't see a reason why that would not work if you were running the code exactly as given and there was no problem with `my_data`.

Comment: Thanks, in the interactive session this works so far. But is there any way I can do this in from an R script? Because I have a lot of data to plot and doing it in an interactive session would be very tedious

Comment: @bluewoodtree ??? What are you going on about!? I've shown you *how* to do that - wrap the `levelplot()` call in `print()`. If that isn't working then something else is wrong and you haven't provided anywhere near enough information to start diagnosing what is wrong. What I show about *does* work for me in a non-interactive session (or when `source()`-ing a script (`.R` file).

Comment: I am sorry, I had another issue, but the problem is solved now, thanks!